# ListItem/TextView in Preference Activity

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

I am using preferenceactivity for my settings feature in project. Everything is perfect. I just ran into one problem that i don't know how to pass. I want a ListItem which is clickable, basically a textview that we see in listview. I want a clickable item in preference activity like textview that starts another activity. But i couldn't find how to add. There are checkboxpreference/listpreference etc. I have been using that for my presference setting purpose. Here is my preference xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    xmlns:threefiftyprefs="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.farter.accelero" >    
    <PreferenceCategory
        android:title="Application">
        <ListPreference
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_orientation_flag"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_orientation_flag"
            android:key="@string/pref_key_flag_orientation"
            android:entries="@array/orientation_label"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entryValues="@array/orientation_values"
            android:persistent="true"
            />
        <ListPreference
            android:summary="@string/pref_summary_axis_flag"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_axis_flag"
            android:key="@string/pref_key_flag_axis"
            android:entries="@array/axis_label"
            android:defaultValue="1"
            android:entryValues="@array/axis_values"
            android:persistent="true"
            />

    </PreferenceCategory>

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Phrase">
          <CheckBoxPreference
               android:key="phras1"
               android:title="a"
               android:defaultValue="true"/>
          <CheckBoxPreference
               android:key="phra2"
               android:title="b"
               android:defaultValue="true"/>
          <CheckBoxPreference
               android:key="phra3"
               android:title="c"
               android:defaultValue="true"/>
          <CheckBoxPreference
               android:key="phra4"
               android:title="d"
               android:defaultValue="true"/>
          <CheckBoxPreference
               android:key="phra5"
               android:title="e"
               android:defaultValue="true"/>          
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

Where to add an clickable view item and how to get that view to add click listener for starting new activity. Just need idea or snippet.

Thanks.

Comment: I have answered earlier post,look into this ..http://stackoverflow.com/a/7618881/874752

Comment: thanks a lot. This is what i needed. I didn't knew about <preference> element. thanks again

Comment: If you are really benifited this link,vote me up for others references.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<PreferenceScreen android:title="Your title">
            <intent  android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW" 
    android:targetPackage="com.your.package" 
    android:targetClass="com.your.package.YourActivity" />          
</PreferenceScreen>
```